# What free method would you recommend for mounting an Amazon S3 bucket on OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, amazon-s3

It seems s3fs is broken on Snow Leopard
( http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/10/28/leopard-amazon-s3-network-storage )

Does anyone know of a free (and preferably open source) way to mount a bucket so that it can be used from the Finder?

Comment: I created a ticket http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/detail?id=231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, s3fs builds successfully using macports on 10.7.4

Answer (score 0):

[Transmit](http://www.panic.com/TRANSMIT/) supports S3:

> You need to transfer files. Maybe to an FTP or SFTP server, or the
>   cloud via Amazon S3, or using WebDAV. You maintain a website, do
>   backups, or upload photos. You need Transmit, the #1 Mac OS X FTP
>   client.¹ Now, in Transmit 4, we took everything good about Transmit,
>   and added a dollop of unbelievably great.

[image]

Comment: so what? I was asking about mounting volumes.

Comment: although this is not free... i would say it is the best/easiest solution i have come across

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue here is that MacFuse, isn't supported under 10.7 and higher.

> **(From the Macfuse Website):**
>   Please Note: This project is no longer being maintained. We cannot currently help with any lion (or any large feline) related bugs or issues.

Now, they do list a user supported forum, which is also not available...

Your only hope, maybe OSXfuse (http://osxfuse.github.com/ ).  They support OS X 10.5 to 10.7, and claim to offer a mode that allows the user of Macfuse written plugins to work with recompiling.  But I would suggest you check with your S3 filespace plugin author, and check to see if there is an OSXfuse ready version of it.

But keep in mind, that the *fuse packages, have also shown some oddities with Parallels, and VMWare Fusion, for example.

The technology is neat, but since it's not wide spread sometimes issues occur.